# Formula to calculate balance when values are negative

Tags: php

Earning = 10
Withdrawn = -30

Balance = Earning - Withdrawn = 10 - (-30) = 40
The correct value should be -20

How to do it in php if both or either of above values is negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a check, to see if the value is negative, and then, u can do this:

```
$a = 10;
$b = -30;
$op = ($a) - abs($b);

echo "$op";
```

It will return -20

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_abs.asp